# How to preselect Angular-ui-bootstrap autocomplete with appropriate data json object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Listen, I have an angular-ui-bootstrap autocomplete which has list of companies populated in it. As soon as I start typing in the autocomplete field, the appropriate companies popup and I select one of them, works fine!

> So, I don't know what to use in uib-typeahead, just like we use **track by** in ng-options?

Code that I'm using for the angular-ui-bootstrap autocomplete field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="loadStopForm.customer" uib-typeahead="company as company.businessName for company in allCompanies | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" data-error="Please select a customer" required>
```

JSON array of **allCompanies**

```
[{
   "companyId": 1,
   "companyName": "Coca Cola",
   "companyCode": "COC"
 }, {
   "companyId": 2,
   "companyName": "Pepsi",
   "companyCode": "PEP"
 }, {
   "companyId": 3,
   "companyName": "Sprite",
   "companyCode": "SPR"
}]
```

> Hitherto, everything works fine I am successfully able to find and select a company, but the **problem** is how do I make the field preselected / prefilled when I get this object from the list:

`{
   "companyId": 2,
   "companyName": "Pepsi",
   "companyCode": "PEP"
 }`

I'm able to recieve the object but can't prefill the autocomplete field. Please help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
   "companyId": 2,
   "companyName": "Pepsi",
   "companyCode": "PEP"
 }
```

assign the above value to the ng-model of typehead as below

```
$scope.loadStopForm.customer = {
   "companyId": 2,
   "companyName": "Pepsi",
   "companyCode": "PEP"
 }
```

---

```
<input type="text" ng-model="loadStopForm.customer" uib-typeahead="company as company.companyName for company in allCompanies | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" data-error="Please select a customer" required>
```

Comment: @ShenoyD'Souza I just gave the example of the object, I don't which object I am gonna get.

Comment: I am getting exactly $scope.loadStopForm.customer, so no need to assign.

Comment: @ShenoyD'Souza use this plunkr to make changes https://plnkr.co/edit/bAOiWGsepkAx9GMw0xnq?p=preview

Comment: Whatever dynamic value you get assign the value to the ng-model.. the dynamic value assiging to the ng-model must be a object of the form { "companyId": somevalue, "companyName": "somevalue" }